# creating a unique service instances using Componentfactory by without using servicefactory in OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, service-factory

I am trying to use component factory in OSGi. My intention is to create instances of Class A, which is exposed as a factory, using Class B, which is a factory manager.
Class A contains some services with @Reference annotations which work fine. 
The same approach is used for Class C, factory (as similar to Class A) with same service references with @Reference.

1. Will it return the same service object to both the class A & Class C?
2. If yes(for question 1), whether service factory will work for the services in class A & Class C?(services with attribute servicefactory inside component factory (class A&C)
3. If not (for question 1), Instead of factories is there any approach to get the unique service object inside Class A & Class C while using @Reference?
4. I can achieve the same using new operator for those services in the class A & class C respectively but I am expecting some kind of DI approach. Is it possible/achievable in DS?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceFactory behavior is independent of DS. Assuming you are not using the new PrototypeServiceFactory in R6, a bundle making multiple gets for a ServiceFactory service will see the same service object. Different bundles will see different service objects (assuming the ServiceFactory implementation returns distinct objects).

So if A and C are in the same bundle, they will see the same service object for referenced services independent of whether the referenced service is a ServiceFactory.

If you need distinct service objects, you should look into PrototypeServiceFactory added in Core R6 and supported in DS 1.3.

Comment: @Hargrave, I am using Karaf 2.3.x branch ,which supports the latest OSGi 4.3 containers. Any other way to achieve this in 4.3 revision?

Comment: Everything is the same in OSGi 4.3 except for the absence of PrototypeServiceFactory. If you do need that, then you need an OSGi runtime which supports the OSGi Core R6 spec.